# Questions about the W3Schools Filter/Search list

Tags: javascript, for-loop, filter, syntax, comparison

Here's what I've been looking at:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Here's the full code (from W3Schools):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So my questions mainly are about stuff in the for-loop.

1) `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];`

Why do you need to specify the index of the anchors when there is only 1 of them in each of the list items? It seems like you wouldn't have to, but when you remove the [0] then the "a" variable becomes undefined.

2) `a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1`

Can someone explain what this line means? If I understand correctly, "indexOf(filter)" should return a number, and "a.innerHTML.toUpperCase()" a string. Is this shorthand for a comparison? If so, shouldn't it return true or false? Since 0 is false and everything above it is true, why -1?

Comment: You should try and ask once question at a time

Comment: getElementsByTagName will always return a list of items even if there is only one (but it could also be none or many). That is why you need to get the first element from this list/array

Answer (score 1):

1) a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

Why do you need to specify the index of the anchors when there is only 1 of them in each of the list items? It seems like you wouldn't have to, but when you remove the [0] then the "a" variable becomes undefined.

**Answer**
getElementsByTagName will always return a list of items even if there is only one (but it could also be none or many). That is why you need to get the first element from this list/array

2) a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1

Can someone explain what this line means? If I understand correctly, "indexOf(filter)" should return a number, and "a.innerHTML.toUpperCase()" a string. Is this shorthand for a comparison? If so, shouldn't it return true or false? Since 0 is false and everything above it is true, why -1?

**Answer**

```
a.innerHTML
```

Selects the inner HTMl from the a element

```
a.innerHTML.toUpperCase()
```

Will make the text in the a element uppercase so you can find a match for filter which has also been upper cased so the strings will match

```
.indexOf(filter)
```

Finds the fist occurrence of filter in the text within the a element/tag. If the text in filter is found then indexOf will return the position within the string which will be 0 or higher. If the text in filter wasn't found then indexOf returns **-1**
 [Here are the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
```

Comparing the result to be greater then -1 make this a boolean expression resulting in true/false

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you need to specify the index of the anchors when there is only 1 of them in each of the list items?

Because getElementsByTagName returns a sequence of the elements, and you need any index into the sequence.  Note that a sequence works in the case of no elements, a single element, or many elements. It's good to be able to treat all the cases the same.  Otherwise you'd have to check for null, a sequence, or a single element.

> If I understand correctly, "indexOf(filter)" should return a number, and "a.innerHTML.toUpperCase()" a string.

Right.  So `a.innerHtml.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)` is a number.  If filter appears in the string produced by `a.innerHtml.toUpperCase()`, then you'll get the index of the location, which will be greater than or equal to 0. That's the same as greater than -1.